# What does #define ArrayLength(x) (sizeof(x)/sizeof(*(x))) mean?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

What does this line exactly mean?

It is clear what define is, but I don't understand why is passing the pointer of x at the denominator:

```
#define ArrayLength(x) (sizeof(x)/sizeof(*(x)))
```

thanks

Comment: Just in case anyone reading the question is in doubt, the macro is used to avoid having error-prone constructs like `int a[]={1,2,3}; foo(a, sizeof(a)/sizeof(int));` all over the code (instead `foo(a, ArrayLength(a))` can be used).

Comment: @user786653 Is see. So this is how to get the array length in C ?using the allocated memory ? Isn't there a built-in method providing such information ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### The denominator

```
sizeof(*(x))
```

is the **length of the first element in the array** in bytes. The variable `x` is of an array type, and it *[decays](http://boredzo.org/pointers/#arrays)* to a pointer, pointing to the start of the array. The asterisk (`*`) is the [dereference operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator), so `*(x)` means *"the data pointed to by `x`"*.

### The numerator

```
sizeof(x)
```

applies the `sizeof` operator to an *array type*. This gives **the length of the entire array** in bytes.

### The macro could also be written as

```
#define ArrayLength(x) (sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]))
```

which is perhaps easier to read.

Comment: That should be "(sizeof(x)/sizeof ((x)[0]))". But I still agree that the [0] form is easier to read ;-)

Comment: @wildplasser, just out of curiosity, can you provide an example of an array type argument `x`, which would break the macro without the extra parens? I couldn't find such a case, where `x` wouldn't decay into a pointer due to being a part of an expression. I totally agree with "if in doubt, add parens" to be on the safe side, though `:)`

Comment: Well, I cannot provide an example. But I cannot prove either that such an example does not exist ;-)  Anyway: [] binds very tight in C; only function() binds tighter.

Answer (score 2):

That pointer is getting the first object in the array. Is it clearer if I were to write it like this:

```
sizeof(entireArray) / sizeof(firstObjectInArray)
```

Comment: A pedantic point - it doesn't get the first object in the array. Because it is the operand to the sizeof() operator it is used only to determine type of which to get the size, not dereference the pointer. That makes it safe to do this (or at least to not have to consider this) situation: "int *x = NULL; int sx = sizeof(*x);"

Comment: That is pedantic, but valid nonetheless. Worth the comment =]

Comment: to be even more pedantic: the syntax is "sizeof expr", so expr does not have to be an object. The other syntax "sizeof(typename)" needs parentheses. The confusion arises because "expr" may or may not be parenthesized.  Always putting () around preprocessor macro arguments used inside the macro body is however a good habit.

Answer (score 0):

it turns out to be something like this

```
int a[]={1,2,3};
 foo(a, sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]));
```

which in your case will be

```
 foo(a, sizeof(a)/sizeof(1));
```

i.e size of integer

```
 foo(a, sizeof(a)/sizeof(int));
```

you can also go with passing enum as constant in the denominator enum may be something like this

```
enum dataType {
    INT    = 2,
    fLOAT = 4,
    DOUBLE = 8
 }type;
```

This will help while deploying your code to different environment like from dos to windows etc. but i guess that can be true in orignal snippet also. but enum approach will increase the performance i guess.