# Avoid boilerplate syntax sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]) in C

Tags: c, syntax, sizeof

I often write this:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(some_variable) / sizeof(some_variable[0]); i++) {
   // ...
}
```

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331405/what-does-define-arraylengthx-sizeofx-sizeofx-mean) I can also write a MACRO such as:

```
#define ArrayLength(x) (sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]))
```

However I feel this is not really a good solution to obfuscate this very simple thing under a macro.

Is there any better alternative defined by C99 or C11?

Because of this boilerplate syntax I often find my colleagues to hard code the size of the variable or worse, use a `define` like this:

```
#define ELEMENTS 23
int foo[ELEMENTS];
for (size_t i; i < ELEMENTS; i++);
```

Comment: What sort of alternative? Are you looking for some API?

Comment: A macro is as good as it gets, to my knowledge

Comment: No, Also note that the code above will not work if `some_variable` is passed to a function as a parameter

Comment: In `stddef` you can find for instance `offsetof` which is really useful. It is a standardized way to fetch the offset member in a structure. I am looking for something similar to this perhaps called `elementsof`

Comment: I prefer writing it out, it is clearer, if you find it too long, put as a const before loop and let the optimizer do its job.

Comment: What is bad on `#define ELEMENTS 23` and `int foo[ELEMENTS];` ... ?

Comment: @Marian It is useless because you loose a precious information: `ELEMENTS` belongs to `foo`. If you only use `ELEMENTS` for `foo` and to iterate through it, it is much better to use the `sizeof(foo) / sizeof(foo[0])` instead. Also, you make your code more difficult to read because the size of `foo` cannot be directly read, you have to look for `ELEMENTS` that will be likely found somewhere above.

Comment: @nowox `for (size_t i; i < ELEMENTS; i++);` is not _useless_.  The best coding practice often depends on the larger code context and the style guide employed by the group.

Comment: @chux Coding practices are subjective, but strongly depends on common sense and thus to fundamental values *i.e.* [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself), [SSOT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_source_of_truth), [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) that should apply to any programming language. In fact, the term `useless` wasn't carefully chosen. I would have said instead `ELEMENTS` doesn't do very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best thing to do, by a country mile, is to maintain a *separate* parameter for the number of elements in the array.

Then all those bugs that creep in, due to pointer decay, when you move code into a *function* will no longer occur.

Failing that, always spell out the `sizeof` idiom longhand.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's nothing *new* that can help you. You have to stick with either of aforesaid option.

That said, in my personal opinion, while defining and using a MACRO is definitely a correct and viable option,

```
 for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(some_variable) / sizeof(some_variable[0]); i++) {
```

is the *better choice*, it does not leave the *human* reader wondering about the actual implementation or purpose, for that matter. Any half-decent compiler will perform the required optimization (*applicable whatsoever*), anyway.

Comment: It's a good choice but it is often larger than 76 or 80 chars so if you want to be MISRA compatible you HAVE to break the line in pieces.

Comment: @nowox Well, I don't disagree, but that's a limitation for a specific subset, nothing from the native language side, is it? :)

Comment: It's not really a problem if this macro is a utility defined in a very basic header used across an entire project. Users become literate in the use of this macro very fast.

Comment: @StoryTeller As I already said, it's a matter of choice. As the writer, I'd love to use the MACRO, but as a reader, I'd love to see the expansion. :)

Comment: @nowox You don't have to break a line. Use a variable that stores the size.

Comment: I agree it's a matter of taste. Just figured it's worth presenting both sides of the argument ;)

Comment: Perhaps I'm an old dogmatist but I would go altogether ballistic if someone used a macro for this - due to concerns around pointer decay if the loop was moved into to a function, and the array passed to it.

Comment: There may be tricks you could use to have the macro produce an error if passed a pointer.

Comment: @R.. How could you possibly detect if a identifier is an array? (_Generic doesn't count)